# How to declare a generic function that returns a function (react hook) with same parameters but different return type from its parameter

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, How can I declare a function **f** that follows the rules above?

**f** is a function that:

- takes another function **callback** as a parameter; and
- returns a different function **hook**;
- where **hook** accepts the same parameters as **callback** but has a
  **different return type**.

*Emphasis on "different return type"*...

My specific goal is to type a React Hook I implemented, but my question is not related to the hook itself. Rather, it's with the type declaration.

I am very close to the solution, but there is still a missing piece... Based on [this answer from a different but similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998417/create-a-generic-function-returning-a-function-with-the-same-signature#answer-28998603), I was able to add a type hint to the function correctly covering the parameters, but this approach lies about the return type:

Here is my code:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function useTimeoutDebounce<F extends Function>(callback: F, ms: number): F {
    const timeout = useRef<number>();
    const timeoutDebounce = (...args: any[]) => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            window.clearTimeout(timeout.current);
            timeout.current = window.setTimeout(() => {
                callback(...args)
            }, ms);
        }
    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
    return <any>timeoutDebounce;
}
```

With that code in place, I'm able to use it like so:

[image: useTimeoutDebounce being used with type hint]

Notice that TypeScript successfully checks the types for the parameters! Great!

However, look at this other example, ***(This is the behavior I want to change)***:

[image: Example where callback function returns a boolean value]

Notice that the hook's return type is `boolean`, which is a lie. As you can see in the hook declaration, it is a void function.

I am thinking of the long run. Having the type hint lying about the return type of a function will eventually cause problems when maintaining the code.

P.s.: I looked at the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type, but I couldn't make it work for my case because it doesn't work with **Function**.

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype):

```
type T7 = Parameters<Function>;
Type 'Function' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any): any'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the solution would look something like this (I have written it as what I believe is a minimal reproducible example for your problem).

In the case below you can see that the aToC function was constructed from the aToB function, it ends up with the same parameter signature but a different return value. There is a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBEMkG4CwAoUkoCEFl91tdoBhIpC0rbAMwFcA7AY2AEsB7FqAJwjkAYqw48WAHgAKAQ36yAtgGcoEAB7AILACarZLEAG0AugD4AFMxYAuKBYB0TsPKXKbchSoCUCM-l87R2dXFQ9Q5V94MyoAb2woRIEhJn4%20YIcXL3dPNyizZFpsAF9sRjEuXihZABVufAtZGxhvG3x4rCTBYFS%20JBI0KBKyrDZeZWBquqpEbvAIUXZKlka6gMx6LCA) for it which shows it compiles where you can hover over aToC to check the type and experiment from there.

```
type A = "A";
type B = "B";
type C = "C";

function retypeFunction<Params extends any[]>(fun: (...params:Params) =>B) : (...params:Params) =>C {
    return (...params:Params) => "C"
}

function aToB(a:A):B{
   return "B"; 
}

const aToC = retypeFunction(aToB);
```

Comment: This question solved my problem, thank you!

One thing to add here is that `fun`'s return type can be generic as well:

`function retypeFunction<Params extends any[], T>(fun: (...params:Params) => T) : (...params:Params) =>C { ...`

With that, we don't need to know the return type of it beforehand.

Comment: Right, I wanted to keep it simple but should have clarified the general case. Glad it helped.